# Can I grep for text in multiple files and output the results to a single .csv?

Tags: macos, grep

I've got a couple of hundred flat html files, each of which contains some data that I'd like to output to a single csv.

eg:

```
<meta property="og:latitude" content="50.079176">
<meta property="og:longitude" content="-5.694866">
```

Can I recursively grep for these two lines, and output a line in the csv like so:

> filename, 50.079176, -5.694866

Is this possible from the mac command line, or would I need a bash script? Or maybe grunt could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really should be using is a proper command-line HTML parser like [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html), but here is a dirty (non-`GNU`) `awk` solution that should work on OS X:

```
$ cat t.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function extr(s) {
    sub(/^.+content="/, "", s);
    sub(/".*$/, "", s);
    return s;
}

/og:latitude/  && /content/ { latitude  = extr($0) }
/og:longitude/ && /content/ { longitude = extr($0); exit }
# the above exit will speed things up but obviously requires
# that the latitude property always precedes the longitude property
# in your files

END {
    if (latitude && longitude)
        printf "%s,%s,%s\n", FILENAME, latitude, longitude
}
```

.

```
$ find . -name "*.html" -exec ./t.awk {} \;
bar.html,51.123456,-4.654321
foo.html,50.079176,-5.694866
```

Here's a `bash` version which iterates over all `.html` files in the current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.html; do
    [ -f "${file}" ] || continue
    latitude=
    longitude=
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        case ${line} in
            *og:latitude*content=*)
                latitude=${line##*content=\"}
                latitude=${latitude%%\"*}
                ;;
            *og:longitude*content=*)
                longitude=${line##*content=\"}
                longitude=${longitude%%\"*}
                ;;
            *) ;;
        esac
    done < "${file}"
    [[ -n ${latitude} && -n ${longitude} ]] && echo "${file},${latitude},${longitude}"
done
```

.

```
$ ./test.sh
bar.html,51.123456,-4.654321
foo.html,50.079176,-5.694866
```

Comment: Thanks very much Adrian - that bash script worked like a charm (I added 'find' to the for loop so that I could recursively search directories) - I'm going to look at xidel right now!